# Why is Anubis given a scarf in some representations?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt, art

Two links containing images of Anubis with scarf;

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis_Shrine

https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis

In some representations Anubis wears what seems to be a scarf. Why is he wearing a ‘scarf’ around his neck? Anubis seems only to wear it in dog/jackal form and in relation to shrines.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The depiction of Anubis in jackal form wasn't meant to suggest he was actually a wild animal. Representing Anubis as a jackal was simply a device to visually convey his identity, qualities and attributes.  He was still one of the Ennead (the original 9 most important, Egyptian Gods of the Heliopolis cosmogony), so a gold scarf would be appropriate 'dress'.

Comment: To clarify my question I removed the domesticated animal part. The question is why a scarf? It is golden in one link but red in the other. Again the question is not about what material or whether it is appropriate dress. The question is about the choice of dress for this particular pose of Anubis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sash you refer to is discussed at the [Western Australian Museum](http://museum.wa.gov.au/whats-on/afterlife/curators-introduction/anubis) website:

> When he is shown as a seated jackal/dog, Anubis often has a
>   ribbon/sash tied around his neck. This looped red sash is a version of
>   the sa sign, a word often translated as amulet, and it symbolised the
>   protection of female deities. Not only Anubis wears this sash, it is
>   also worn at the king’s waist and by gods and goddesses, again
>   symbolising protective power.